# Sweet Alert Woocommerce Add to Cart Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, sweetalert

I have a plugin that changes Wordpress Woocommerce variations to a table format. I have modified quite a bit of the code. I am trying to implement **Sweet Alerts 2** instead of the alerts it give now for when a user successfully adds a product to the cart (or shows error.)

The original code in the js file that handles the alert is here through end of file.

```
    $.ajax({

        'url' : wcvw_urls.ajax_url,

        'method' : 'POST',

        dataType:"json",

        data : data,

        success: function(res){

            if(res.type === 'success'){

                 main_container.find('.wcvw_messages').html(res.message).fadeIn('slow');

                $this.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');

            }else{

                main_container.find('.wcvw_messages').html(res.message).fadeIn('slow');

                $this.addClass('').removeClass('loading');
            }
           },
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

The code I am trying to get to work kinda works... but acts weird. I don't know much javascript, so I know I am not doing something correct. When I click the button, it will add the product to the cart, but the sweet alert isn't activating until like the 3rd click, but then works. But only works for the first product in the list. Maybe needs a foreach loop?

Here is the a link to my page if you want to see how it is acting...
http://192.163.245.60/~oti/product/asfs-1100-v-series/

Just click the Add to Quote on first product a few time. The second product should give an error but doesn't. The third should add products.

Here is my modified code I am trying to implement.

```
    $.ajax({

        'url' : wcvw_urls.ajax_url,

        'method' : 'POST',

        dataType:"json",

        data : data,

        success: function(res){

            if(res.type === 'success'){
                //ORIGINAL CODE
                // main_container.find('.wcvw_messages').html(res.message).fadeIn('slow');

                //Added Sweet Alert Success//
                document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-success').onclick = function() {
                swal({
                     title: 'Product Added to Quote!',
                    type: 'success',
                    html:
                        '<div><a class="fusion-button button-flat button-square button-large button-default button-1" href="http://192.163.245.60/~oti/cart/">Send Quote Now!</a></div><br />',
                    timer: 10000, 
                    confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Continue Shopping', 
                    showCloseButton: false,
                    showCancelButton: false,
                    });
                };
                //End Success Sweet Alert//
                $this.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');

            }else{
                //ORIGINAL CODE
                //main_container.find('.wcvw_messages').html(res.message).fadeIn('slow');

                //Added Sweet Alert Error//
                document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-error.sweet').onclick = function(){
                swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong! Please try again!", "error");
                    };
                //End Error Sweet Alert//
                $this.addClass('').removeClass('loading');
             }
           },
        });
     });
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I click the button, it will add the product to the cart, but the sweet alert isn't activating until like the 3rd click, but then works.But only works for the first product in the list.

This is because the first button click sends your ajax request, and then when it returns you are binding the sweet alert as a click handler to the click event of "document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-success')". In other words the first click is binding the event, subsequent clicks, after it is bound, will trigger the sweet alert.

> Just click the Add to Quote on first product a few time. The second product should give an error but doesn't. The third should add products.

All three buttons have the classes "add-to-cart-success add-to-cart-error sweet" and document.querySelector() only returns the first element that matches the query, so for both success and error your click handlers will bind to the first button only. You will only ever return a success, so the success alert is the only one you ever see.

The easiest fix would be to remove "document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-success').onclick = function() {}" and "document.querySelector('.add-to-cart-error.sweet').onclick = function(){}" entirely. The draw back to this is the alert will not show until the ajax request returns. This is good because you are not presenting false information. You only know whether to show a success or failure alert after the request returns.

If you want to give the user an indicator as soon as they click the button, and then update the alert when the request returns, then you could bind a basic alert to the button click, and then have the alert from the ajax request over ride it when your request returns.

JQuery:

```
(function($){

// Button click event binding
$(document).on('click','.wcvw_varition_add_to_cart', function(){  

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
    var main_container = $('.wcvw_main_container');
    var rows = $(this).closest('.wcvw_row_of_items');
    var qty_data = rows.find('.wcvw_quantity input').val();

    if(qty_data=="" || qty_data==undefined){
        qty_data = 1;   
    }

    var data = {

        'action' : 'add_varition_product_into_cart',
        'product_id' : $this.attr('data-id'),
        'qty' : qty_data
    };

    // Initial alert when button is clicked
    swal({
        title: 'Adding to Quote...',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false
    })

    $.ajax({
        'url' : wcvw_urls.ajax_url,
        'method' : 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data : data,
        success: function(res){

            if(res.type === 'success'){

                //Added Sweet Alert Success//
                swal({
                    title: 'Product Added to Quote!',
                    type: 'success',
                    html:
                        '<div><a class="fusion-button button-flat button-square button-large button-default button-1" href="http://192.163.245.60/~oti/cart/">Send Quote Now!</a></div><br />',
                    timer: 10000, 
                    confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Continue Shopping', 
                    showCloseButton: false,
                    showCancelButton: false,
                    });

                //End Success Sweet Alert//
                $this.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');

            }else{

                //Added Sweet Alert Error//
                swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong! Please try again!", "error");
                //End Error Sweet Alert//
                $this.addClass('').removeClass('loading');
            }
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This make sense. Thank you for the explanation. I really didn't know how Ajax worked. This works perfect! Thanks!